# Jedi naval ranks?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6513/why-are-all-jedi-given-a-rank-of-general-in-the-clone-wars?rq=1) question answers a question I had regarding Star Wars Generals and why Jedi are a part of it. I realized something a bit odd when reading the question though. If the Jedi are always placed as Generals, why are there others in charge of the Starships (Admiral Tench, etc.)?

In Star Wars: The Clone Wars animated cartoon, we see the Jedi commanding ships and such, but in normal military settings, you usually have to have a communication between different branches, but this isn't seen in the show.

**The Question** 
**What ranks do the Jedi hold within each branch of the Republic military other than General?**

Comment: Similar question here http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99699/what-is-the-difference-between-a-general-and-an-admiral

Comment: I have already answer this question here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119643/how-is-the-republic-military-divided/119748#119748

Comment: @rand al'thor The tag description for Military-SF is "Military science fiction is a sub-genre of science fiction for which the principal characters are members of a military service and an armed conflict is occurring, often in space or on a planet other than Earth [excerpted from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_scifi)". This fits exactly with that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer in the Wikia that states similar to what I am asking, but still loses me on specific ranks.

> The ranks held by members of the Galactic Republic Military varied by era, for instance, during the Old Sith Wars the rank of Captain, or more accurately Fleet Captain was used to refer to Admirals. **Commander was given as a general title reflecting someone in command but not as a specific rank.** Also, due to the diversity of the members of the military, regulations specified that any personnel of higher rank than oneself, regardless of the species, gender or position was to be addressed as "sir". The military answered ultimately to the Supreme Chancellor and the Galactic Senate. Though the Republic Army and Republic Navy had similar ranks, there were some variations.

This gives the general rank of Commander, but doesn't allow for specifics. So I can assume that the rank of "Commander" was given to all Jedi as an all encompasing rank, meaning something closer to "superior" than an actual ranked Commander. It is listed in the following quote specifically what the ranks given during the Clone Wars were.

> The Jedi Order took command of the military coordinated by the Jedi Command and under the supervision of the Senate. **Along with Jedi Commanders, clones with special training were given ranks of Commander to assist in leading the army.**

This mostly answers my question, but opens up another question as to how is the Republic military divided (For example, is it Air Force, Navy, and Army?)

Answer (score 4):

Jedi Knights are given the rank of "General" and command ground troops (Clone Troopers). They have their own private combat vessels that are deployed from carriers, but they do not command starships.

Padawans, such as Ahsoka Tano, are given the rank of "Commander".

I would consider both ranks as leaders of ground troops. For consistency with our modern forces, it should be Colonel, not Commander, but sci-fi always seems to get it wrong. I guess Commander sounds cooler.

Admirals (non-Jedi) command carriers and other starships. The Admirals may defer to the Jedi when forming battle plans, but they are in charge of their own ships.

From the article [Admiral](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Admiral) in Wookieepedia:

> Admiral was a senior command rank in many navies and starfleets,
>   including those of the Galactic Republic the Galactic Empire, the
>   Confederacy of Independent Systems and the Alliance to Restore the
>   Republic.

From the article [General](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/General/) in Wookieepedia:

> During the Clone Wars, many Jedi Knights and Masters were given the
>   rank of general in the Republic army.

Note the distinction between "navies and starfleets" and "army".

Comment: It specifically mentions "General Kenobi's Fleet" in the series though. In the wikia here, it mentions the different fleet, as well as Anaking leading a group of Y-Wings, which would need a naval/Air Force rank (as the Y-wing would still be considered either a "ship" or a "fighter jet"). http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Republic_Navy

Comment: That's an example of writers who never served in the military making education guesses. It is common within science fiction. In our day, fighter jets are either Navy or Air Force, and ground troops are Army or Marine Corps. In sci-fi, a character is often both a pilot and a leader of ground troops.

Comment: Generals and admirals are both general flag officers. Admiral is simply a specialize name for s general officer in a naval context. It makes sense that Jedi would be generals because they understand battle, however they may not have the specialize knowledge required to command a ship, which has a specialized set of skills beyond simply maneuverability and firepower.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there are Marines who disagree with you, @CigarDoug. Given the opportunity, they may want to introduce you to their Hornets and Harriers.

Comment: Oh, I know of my brothers who don't like to walk. I was speaking in general. Hell, the Army has more small boats than the Navy! My point is, scifi lumps pilots and ground troops together, which is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

During the Clone War Jedi were instantly promoted to resume the ranks of the Grand Army.

1. With Jedi padawans having the rank of Commander (leading battalions and regiments of troops)
2. Jedi knights were appointed as "*Generals*" (leading legions and armies)
3. Jedi Masters were "*Senior Generals*" leading System armies and special warfare units
4. The Jedi councils 12 members were "*High Generals*" were incharge of the entire Army, outside the purview of the Chancellor.

Comment: Can you source this information from canon sources?