# How is the Republic Military divided?

Tags: star-wars

In my question about [Jedi Naval Ranks?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119538/jedi-naval-ranks) I asked what the different ranks were in the Republic military. It came with an all encompassing "Commander" tag for the Jedi, but made me question another piece of the puzzle.

The question left unanswered was **what kind of military branches does the Republic military have, and how are the different forces broken down to allow for a streamlined command structure (Admiral Tench vs General Kenobi, etc.)?**

I'm offering a bounty looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

Canon preferred, Legends canon sources will not be accepted, but speculation may be used if provided in conjunction with listed canon citations.

Comment: Related [What is the difference between a general and an admiral?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99699/what-is-the-difference-between-a-general-and-an-admiral)

Comment: In the Star Wars universe *everyone* is a General or an Admiral.

Comment: @JackBNimble Definitely related, but what are the specific branches? The Air Force of the US military uses Generals, but so does the Army. This is pivotal to the question, but the linked question really helps differentiate between Admiral and General, but doesn't for General (Army) to General (Air Force).

Comment: [military-sf] is a sub-genre of science fiction. Do you add [fantasy-genre] to every fantasy question you ask? I really think that it should be [warfare]. Let's see what meta has to say.

Comment: No, but it's about military sci-fi, not the wars they have within them. This is LITERALLY about the military in science fiction, not the actual fighting and war and therefore is not warfare.

Comment: @Anoplexian Yes, it's about the military in a work of sci-fi, but not about *military sci-fi* the subgenre. See [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9186/what-is-correct-usage-of-military-sf).

Comment: @randal'thor Meta accepted "Someone following it searching on that tag would not immediately be able to answer a question on Jedi commanders, but could more easily answer how Jedi being defacto commanders related to common themes in military sci-fi." As this is a question about the specific military GENRE, not necessarily the fact that it's a Miitary-SF (IE Star Wars), this fits into the Military-SF genre. It's more easily answered by someone with a background in Military-SF rather than Star Wars in general.

Comment: Your bounty text is very confusing. Everything that isn't canon is [Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Legends), including video games like SWTOR.

Comment: @Null I was under the impression that under the old canon system, they were not G-canon or T-canon (which are official), that C-canon was the books for the expanded universe, and that S-Canon was dismissed, but still part of the universe, and then of course N-Canon was not considered. As far as I'm aware, are the games not S-canon (artistic licensing and the such)? EDIT: After looking at the Wookiepedia entry for canon, I missed the section on the specifics. Is there any way to change the bounty?

Comment: The old canon system has basically been flattened into two levels: canon and Legends (i.e. non-canon). Roughly, everything G and T canon is canon but everything else is Legends. Games are tricky, mainly because they can contradict canon -- the new [*Battlefront*, for example, is generally canon except for contradictions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112442/31936).

Comment: I don't think you can change the bounty text, but you can edit your question with what you are looking for. I'd suggest you do that anyway so that the information is still there when the bounty ends.

Comment: @Null Ah, that clears some things up about the whole "canon" issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks for clarifying, and +1.

Answer (score 3):

Republic ranks are as follows:

- Supreme Commander
- General (Army)/Admiral (Navy)
- Colonel (Army)/Commodore (Navy)
- Major (Army)/Group Captain (Navy)
- Captain
- Lieutenant
- Ensign
- Sergeant (Army)/Petty Officer (Navy)
- Corporal
- Specialist
- Private

Note that 'Commander' is not a rank but a function. 
It may be occupied by any person (regardless of rank) if assigned for that purpose.

[Canon Source](http://www.swtor-spy.com/codex/republic-military-ranks/1471/)  (SWTOR codex entry)

Comment: Do you have any references?

Comment: Multiple.Here's one: http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Republic_Military_Ranks

Comment: They belong in the answer, then.

Comment: @Overmind That's for SWTOR which is not considered G-canon, and is also not also not the Republic military.

Comment: @Overmind This would also be good for my other question (if it had actual canon references), but has almost no bearing on this one. It asks how it's divided by branch, not divided internally.

Comment: @Anoplexian G-canon is not "canon" anymore. Everything is Legends or not. ;)

Comment: @T.J.L. Lol alright then let me rephrase. His answer is officially not canon.

Comment: It is canon since it's a codex entry of SWTOR. Unless it states somewhere officially that it is not, it is since SWTOR has the official Lucas logo.

Comment: Disney owns the properties now, not Lucas, and has simplified things to "canon" and apocryphal "Legends". SWTOR didn't make the cut; it is non-canon.

Comment: @Overmind What T.J.L. said, it's no longer canon. Things created by Lucasfilms are not necessarily canon, despite being endorsed by the logo. For instance, NONE of the Battlefront games are considered canon (although they have parts of the movies which are considered so).